# Is there an easy way to switch playback soundcards?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

I recently purchased the roccat kulo headset which comes with a nice USB soundcard, completely functional under linux :). Howsoever I now struggle to easily siwtch between my laptops integrated soundcard, connected to my stereo and my headset connected by the roccat soundcard.
Running `aplay -l` retureturns the following:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]  
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Kulo [ROCCAT Kulo], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I know I could provide a `.asoundrc` howsoever I'd prefer a more straight forward way to switch the output device globally.

Comment: If `pulseaudio` is an option, `pavucontrol` provides a gui to select the output of each stream, and you can do the same using the command line with `pactl`. [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback) explains how.

Comment: What do you mean with "globally"? For already running applications? For all users?

Comment: "globally" should be for already running applications

Answer (score -1):

asoundconf-gtk, included in the AUR package [asoundconf](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/asoundconf/), is a GUI that lets you select the default sound card.

It can be installed via [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/yaourt) with:

```
yaourt -S asoundconf
```

Comment: @HalosGhost I just tried it, and it installed it. I had to choose it from a search-like prompt, is that what you mean?

Comment: Then `yaourt`'s behavior is even less predictable than when I last used it. My -1 for `yaourt` will stay.

Comment: If you call `yaourt` without an an function, it assumes you're using `-Ss`. The right command would be `yaourt -S asoundconf`. This has nothing to do with unpredictability, as it is standard behaviour.