# Alsa mixer for assigning specific apps to a specific soundcard?

Tags: xfce, software-rec, gui, alsa, usb-audio

I am looking for a Alsa mixer GUI for Xfce (or better yet, desktop-independent) to replace PulseAudio Mixer. While I'm happy with the latter, my USB DAC is very poorly handled by PulseAudio and I need to remove it.

In the Alsa-based mixer I am looking specifically for the ability to:

- detect plugged-in USB DACs
- set default playback device for new programs (e.g. to `USB DAC`)
- (optional) transparently change running programs currently outputting sound from one playback device to another (e.g. from integrated `HDA PCH` to `USB DAC`)

So is there a `pavucontrol`-like Alsa mixer out there?

Comment: These features are not implemented by ALSA but by PulseAudio.

Comment: @CL. Can I at least set the default playback device for new programs to the `USB DAC`? I tried things like `QasMixer` or even `alsamixer` to select the USB DAC as device, but new programs would still output things to the builtin laptop soundcard...

Comment: In a mixer, selecting a device just changes which mixer controls are shown *in the mixer*. As for changing the default sound card, this is a different question, which [has been asked before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=default+sound+card).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Alsa doesn't seem to be able to transparently change running programs from one playback device to another, as this is a feature specific to PulseAudio. Moreover, selecting a device in an Alsa mixer will only define which mixer controls are shown *within the mixer*, and it has no bearing on the default sound card used by media players.

There is a minimalistic python GUI that allows to detect plugged-in USB DACs and set the default playback device for new programs: `asouncdconf-gtk` (originally written for Ubuntu with Xfce in mind). This utility relies on the [asoundconf](http://wiki.marklesh.com/How-to/Asoundconf) python script. Even if unmaintained for a number of years (last update in 2011), it seems to still be working alright on modern distros (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04).

[image]

Ubuntu users can install the packages from the [asoundconf PPA](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/ubuntu/asoundconf) (officially Ubuntu has decent support only for PulseAudio). For Arch Linux see [Is there an easy way to switch playback soundcards?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55508/is-there-an-easy-way-to-switch-playback-soundcards). But since it's Python code, it can run virtually on any distro: grab the Ubuntu `.deb`, unpack it with an archive manager, and put the scripts in `/usr/bin`.

---

Alsa's official docs only indicate a [manual way to set a default soundcard](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Setting_the_default_device):

Find the relevant card:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

and then put in `/etc/asound.conf`:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

Replacing "1" with the number of the relevant card. Hardly something you would want to do often, e.g. with a USB DAC.

---

Additional reading:

- [Asoundconf for Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick)](http://wiki.marklesh.com/How-to/Asoundconf) for a longer discussion on Alsa-only vs PulseAudio on Ubuntu distros
- [alsa-utils missing asoundconf](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-utils/+bug/376024) -- Ubuntu devels announcing that they WONTFIX this for Alsa-only users (i.e. force their users to use PulseAudio; seems to be a corporate thing, as Skype has done the same with version 4.3...)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pavucontrol` to set the default (and fallback) audio output device. But this needs pulseaudio (one of the reasons pulse was developed).

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a mixer app that is NOT based on PulseAudio, simply because PulseAudio plays very badly with my USB DAC...

Comment: Alsa can't do this. Alsa is for static setups with one sound card. No need to downvote my answer.

Comment: Surely Alsa allows to set the default playback device for new programs... (As it is, the answer doesn't address my original question.)